# Code coverage analysis for controller test classes

Tags: php, symfony, testing

I would like to know if there were any tools that offer a code coverage analysis for tests classes that test controller. I know there is some for unit testing, but thats not quite what I am looking for.

I am working on a Symfony2 project with a lot of controllers in it, and I wrote some tests to check their behaviour, so now I would like to know how complete they are.

Thanks.

P.S. : Here is an example of what one of my of my tests can looks like

```
public function testSample() {

        $client = $this->createAuthenticatedClient($this->getReference('admin-0')) ;
        $client->followRedirects() ;
        $crawler = $client->request("GET", "/config/database/");
        $this->assertStatusCode(200, $client);

}
```

As you can see, I dont really test my User class, but rather its behaviour depending of its creditential (in this case, an admin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to look at `Functional Tests` based on the sample you show. Think of how you would test all the functionality of the code that you've created in the code. If you think of it in terms of the web, it would be like clicking link and buttons and so on. Whatever a user might do. Take a look at this blog I wrote on [Using Mink to perform Functional Tests in Symfony3](https://alvinbunk.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/using-mink-to-perform-functional-tests-in-symfony3-framework/).

Like @geoB pointed out, you can use the command line:

phpunit --coverage-text

To show your coverage. A sample screenshot of what that looks like is shown below:
[image: phpunit --coverage]

Comment: Your screenshot was really helpful to have an idea of what I should expect. The command works fine, but I had to put a whitelist to get a coherent result.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract of the `phpunit` command:

```
phpunit --help
PHPUnit 5.4.6 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Usage: phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
       phpunit [options] <directory>

Code Coverage Options:

  --coverage-clover <file>  Generate code coverage report in Clover XML format.
  --coverage-crap4j <file>  Generate code coverage report in Crap4J XML format.
  --coverage-html <dir>     Generate code coverage report in HTML format.
  --coverage-php <file>     Export PHP_CodeCoverage object to file.
  --coverage-text=<file>    Generate code coverage report in text format.
                            Default: Standard output.
  --coverage-xml <dir>      Generate code coverage report in PHPUnit XML format.
  --whitelist <dir>         Whitelist <dir> for code coverage analysis.
  --disable-coverage-ignore Disable annotations for ignoring code coverage.
```

Note that you can add parameters that will generate a coverage report **IF xdebug is loaded**.

Comment: I find pretty confusing that the command present itself as a unit test one, but offers code coverage for functionnal test. Anyway, thanks for your help, the whitelist option was really helpful.